# @InstallIn, can only be used with @DefineComponent-annotated classes, but found: [com.abc.xyz.AppClass]

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel, dagger-hilt

As per documentation for Hilt, I completed all the steps

Add Class Path to Project Module

```
classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:$hilt_version"
```

Add Plugins

```
plugins {
    id "kotlin-kapt"
    id("dagger.hilt.android.plugin")
}
```

Add Dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version")
}
```

Annotated Application Class, in my case AppClass, with `@HiltAndroidApp`. Annotated Activity and regarding fragment with `@AndroidEntryPoint`.

Created Module as

```
@InstallIn(AppClass::class)
@Module
object DatabaseModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideAppDB(application: Application): AppDB {
        return AppDB.getDatabase(application)
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideMediaDao(appDB: AppDB): MediaDao {
        return appDB.downloadMediaDao()
    }
}
```

Injected it in ViewModel class as

```
@HiltViewModel
class DownloadViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val mediaDao: MediaDao
): ViewModel() {
    ...
}
```

But After following all the steps I got the error saying "@InstallIn, can only be used with @DefineComponent-annotated classes, but found: [com.abc.xyz.AppClass]"

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As defined in the [Codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-hilt#6), I replaced this

```
@InstallIn(AppClass::class)
```

with this

```
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
```

And it's working.

Comment: But why? Maybe more explanation would be useful?

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I made a career-ending error and I was duly punished by spending the whole day stuck on a simple typo!

Instead of using **SingletonComponent::class** I misspelt it as *Singleton::class*

```
//worst error of my career
@Module
@InstallIn(Singleton::class)
object AppModule { ... }
```

I changed to SingletonComponent::class and bypassed the error.

```
//changed it to this
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule { ... }
```